# Properly updating the QGIS default style database from Python

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, color-ramp

Let's say I copied an existing color ramp from my QGIS profile's default style database, inverted it and saved it under a new name in the database:

```
>>> default_style = QgsStyle.defaultStyle()
>>> color_ramp = default_style.colorRamp("Reds")
>>> color_ramp.invert()  # inplace!
>>> default_style.saveColorRamp(name="Inverted Reds", ramp=color_ramp, favorite=False, tags=[])
True
```

At this moment the new color ramp does exist in the `symbology-style.db` file (so `default_style.save()` is not necessary (nor does it fix the issue below)).

But:

```
>>> default_style.colorRamp("Inverted Reds")
None
```

And the color ramp is not shown in the QGIS GUI anywhere.

What do I have to do to fully registered a newly added style entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saveColorRamp` does not get you the expected result because it only writes the data to the database.
It doesn't update the `mColorRamps` member variable of `QgsStyle` which keeps track of the color ramps at runtime.

To save a color ramp to the style use the function [`addColorRamp`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsStyle.html#a34f7e864038bbb68634d9613acd69b81) before calling `saveColorRamp`. Looking at the source code that's how QGIS does it in most parts.

```
default_style = QgsStyle.defaultStyle()
color_ramp = default_style.colorRamp("Reds")

color_ramp.invert()

default_style.addColorRamp("Inverted Reds", color_ramp)
default_style.saveColorRamp(name="Inverted Reds", ramp=color_ramp, favorite=True, tags=[])

print(default_style.colorRamp("Inverted Reds"))
```

Or if you don't need to specify `favorite` or `tags` then you can also use the `update` parameter set to `true`. `addColorRamp` will directly call  `saveColorRamp` with default arguments.

```
default_style = QgsStyle.defaultStyle()
color_ramp = default_style.colorRamp("Reds")
color_ramp.invert()

default_style.addColorRamp("Inverted Reds", color_ramp, update=True)

print(default_style.colorRamp("Inverted Reds"))
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you! I wish the documentation wasn't that tight-lipped. :)